# Google Play Alpha Release - how to test in app purchases

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have just developed and deployed an app to the Google Play Store.

[image]

As you can see, it is an alpha release. I have read that alpha releases can have their in-app purchases tested, without the tester having to incur a charge.

I have set up closed testing and assigned myself as a tester. I then download the app through the Play Store on my devise. I then attempt to test the in-app purchases, but I get the following:

[image]

As you can see, I cannot make the purchase as I don't have sufficient funds.

**Question**

How do you test in-app purchases so you are not charged?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Adding a user to the alpha does change his purchases to be a mock purchase.

In order to test purchases you need to add your email to the list of accounts with testing access:

1. Go to Google play console
2. Settings -> Account Details -> License Testing
3. Add the your email to the list. Make sure that the you login to the play store with the same email.
4. Make sure to pick RESONSE_NORMALLY in the 'License Test Response'. Later on you can test other types of responses from the store.

Once you have that setup, you can make purchases from that account. When you purchase you will get a message from the play store saying that this is a test purchase and that your account will not be charged.

This is how it looks like - [image]

For more information see https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Comment: Hi little, thank you.  I have just tried that, I added a test user, and see the prompt as you posted above, which I made the purchase, but it didn't complete. Now it seems to have broken the in-app purchases altogether. I get the following error. If you have any suggestions, I would appreciate your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633036/google-play-error-retrieving-sku-details

Comment: Make sure to also set the same tester e-mail address on the list of your alpha/beta release app.

Comment: After the changes, testers can begin making purchases of your in-app products within 15 minutes. See more here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases